# Tool Identification

Tags: tool-identification

I picked this up at a yard sale for ~$2 about 6 months ago and have been trying to figure out what the heck it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Not sure what this thing is]

**UPDATE 4/26/20** - added more pictures.

And yes, it does pivot - there seems to be a spring of some sort in there.

[image: new pic 1]
[image: new pic 2]
[image: new pic 3]
[image: new pic 4]

**UPDATE 4/27/20**

While there doesn't seem to be complete understanding, it sounds like a double marking gauge of some sort. I appreciate everyone's assistance on this! I'll have to figure out if it's worth me trying to understand it, or repurpose the pieces into something more interesting!

Comment: Oh Goody. another, what tool is this question. I think marking gauge of some kind. More photos please, Especially of the little metal nubs on the ends.

Comment: We could do with further pics. From the single image it looks like the two bars are connected by a pivot at the top, but that could be an accident of placement and I can't imagine how that would work. And what's in the small plastic container, are they blades of some sort? If they are do they have a 90° bend near one end? It kinda looks like they do in the photo but I don't know if I'm just talking myself into seeing that and can't figure how they're held.

Comment: I had sort of imagined the blades to slot in... kinda like this: https://www.amazon.ca/Marking-Gauge-Nihon-Sao-Kebiki/dp/B07G4C6SDX . To the OP: do the shiny things at the end tighten to lock the blades?

Comment: Hey all - added more pictures.
@Graphus - they do pivot at the top. Yes, double sided blades.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - they do tighten where I would imagine blades would go

Comment: The spring part in the pivot is fascinating. Is there any way you could extend the beam to double length and still lock it in place?

Comment: I can't figure it out completely but I do think this is a kind of double-beam marking gauge, making @AloysiusDefenestrate's Answer correct which is why I upvoted it. The blades should slip into the narrow slots cut for them and are held in place by the turnscrews at the ends. So this is similar in function to some types of Japanese marking gauge, somewhat like a combination of one of [these](https://www.qy1.de/img/japanisches-streichmass-315862a.jpg) with the top gauge [here](https://www.fine-tools.com/ece-marking-gauges.html). The only thing I can't make sense of is the pivot \*shrug*

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - Yes, I can extend around the pivot for one long piece and can still tighten the bolt at the pivot. When I get around 90 degrees, it wants to spring back to being in alignment (stacked). It's not a strong pull, but if I were holding it in the air it would bounce back a bit.

I'm not sure the purpose of the handle; I can get it to slide in, but there is a giant gap and the black bolt won't quite reach the measuring thing (technical term of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to call that a double marking gauge.

Double because it looks like you can separate the two rods and set them independently. (Useful for marking independent sides of a mortise, for example.)